# How do I pass multi-dimensional arrays of unknown size into a function using pointers in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers

Like the question says, I am trying to pass multi-dimensional arrays into a function to print it to a file for an engineering project. The format for which the data is inputted CANNOT be changed, so please don't suggest I just input it as a different datatype.

This particular function anticipates a two-dimensional array (although I have others with three dimensions after this one), where nothing is known about the size of the array until run-time. I know I must use pointers to point to each row of the array separately, but I have NO idea what the syntax is for passing it to the function. In the following code, the array in question is 'block'. The main function is just a little testing example I made to try to make it work:

```
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

void of_write_blocks(string filename, string block_type[], int **block,
            int grid[][3], string grade_type[], int grade[][3], int n_blocks, int m[])
{
    ofstream file_out(filename.c_str(),ios::app);
    file_out<<"\nblocks\n(\n";

    for(int i=0;i<n_blocks;++i) {
            file_out<<"   "<<block_type[i]<<" ( ";
                    for(int j=0;j<m[i];++j)
                            file_out<<block[i][j]<<" ";
            file_out<<") ( ";
            file_out<<grid[i][0]<<' '<<grid[i][1]<<' '<<grid[i][2]<<" ) ";
            file_out<<grade_type[i]<<" ( ";
            file_out<<grade[i][0]<<' '<<grade[i][1]<<' '<<grade[i][2]<<" )\n";
    }
    file_out<<");\n";
}


//testing example:
int main()
{       
    int block[6][9];
    for(int i=0; i<6;++i) 
            for(int j=0; i<9;++j)
                    block[i][j] = i*j;

    int grid[6][3];
    for(int i=0; i<6;++i)
            for(int j=0; i<3;++j)
                    block[i][j] = i*j;


    int grade[6][3];
    for(int i=0; i<6;++i) 
            for(int j=0; i<3;++j)
                    block[i][j] = i*j;

    string grade_type[6] = {"simpleGrading"};
    string block_type[6] = {"hex"};
    int m[6] = {8};
    int n_blocks = 6;

    of_write_blocks("name",block_type,block,grid,grade_type,grade,n_blocks,m);
}
```

any help is appreciated!

Comment: In the past 25 years, I have never, not even once, had to use a multi-dimensional array. Am I missing out on something?

Comment: @Neil Butterworth try solving the maximum summ contiguous subsequence problem in three dimensions.  I implemented mine in C++ with std::vectors and it required 4 dimensional arrays.

Comment: @user1344784  Fair enough - sounds like the kind of problem I and my various employers have had zero interest in solving. But if I were going to solve such problems, I think I'd use a language where MDAs are first-class objects, like say FORTRAN, which would almost certainly be more performant than C++ in this problem domain.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth, I really wish there was another method. I'm using this program for computational fluid dynamics, and that's how they need it inputted. C++ can be a nuisance for doing engineering-related computations, especially considering I learned Matlab before ever learning C++!

Comment: @Mike Fluid dynamics is a classic area where FORTRAN excels, with many function libraries available. Using C++ would seem to be pure masochism.

Comment: @Neil, yeah pretty much, but I am using software written in C++ (OpenFOAM)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. Multidimensional arrays are syntactic sugar, and are compiled directly into the code that does manipulations on the array, which is a single memory block. The dimensions are not passed into the function as parameters or anything like that as part of the array, as things are done in e.g. Java or C#.

If you need the dimensions of the array in your function, you'll need to just accept a pointer to the first element of the array, and the dimensions, and do the multiplies and adds to get the right index yourself.

Alternately, use something like a `std::vector<std::vector<block>>`, which pass the dimensions as part of the object, rather than a built in array.

Comment: Alright, the dimensions are inputted into the function which helps a lot. I'm not sure how to pass an array into the function, and have the function take it as a pointer. Can you give me a simple example of that syntax?

Comment: There is no such thing as `std::array<block>`, you forgot the size parameter.

Comment: @Fred: Oops. Fixed. You could make a method template with the size of the `std::array` being a size parameter, but that's probably not a good idea....

Comment: Hey Billy, could you please give me an example of how to pass the array into the function as a pointer that simply references the address of the first element of the array. I'm not sure what the syntax would be for that. I think this is what you meant in the second paragraph? (please correct me if I am mistaken)

Comment: @Mike N. `void myfunction(block *multiDimensionalArray);`

Comment: @Billy, if I use that method I get a compile-time error: " cannot convert ‘int (*)[9]’ to ‘int*’ "

Comment: I ended up passing the address of the first element, then just incrementing the pointer based on the number of rows/columns given. All is well!

Comment: @Mike: Yes, that's what you have to do. (Sorry I missed your previous reply)

Answer (score 2):

If you have Boost installed, check out [Boost Multi-Array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html).

Comment: Read.  He can't change the datatype.

Comment: @user1344784: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. Can you highlight the connection between your comment and my suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: The OP said he can't change the data-type, so why are you recommending Boost Multi-Array???

Comment: @user1344784: Well, that's a generic solution and if he is going to operate on only one type then so be it. Boost Multi-array isn't mandating that you should change types.

Answer (score 0):

For clarity I removed all the irrelevant code from your example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void of_write_blocks(int **block, int bh, int bw){

  for(int i = 0; i < bh; ++i)
    for(int j = 0; j < bw; ++j)
      cout << block[i][j] << " ";
  cout << endl;
}

int main(){       

  int bh, bw;
  cin >> bh >> bw;

  int** block;
  block = new int*[bh];
  for(int k = 0; k < bh; k++)
    block[k] = new int[bw];

  // initialize the array
  for(int i = 0; i < bh; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < bw; j++)
      block[i][j] = (i*bw) + j;

  of_write_blocks( block, bh, bw);
}
```

In the main we are creating a 2D array and initializing it.  Then we pass it to of_write_block, which prints the array.  Is that what you wanted to do?

Comment: The problem here is that the size of the array is unknown until run-time, so declaring them as a constant won't work. The function needs to accept input as an array, and the dimensions as local integers to be input directly into the function call, not as global constants.

Comment: @Mike N. the array size can be dynamic.  I changed the code to reflect that.  As far as the array size, you must pass the size to the function like in the example.  There is no other way to know the size.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't use a reference of array. See below example:

```
char c[10];
int i[10][20];
double d[10][20][30];
```

Write a **wrapper** function like this:

```
template<typename T, int SIZE>
void Array (T (&a)[SIZE])
{}
template<typename T, int SIZE1, int SIZE2>
void Array (T (&a)[SIZE1][SIZE2])
{}
template<typename T, int SIZE1, int SIZE2, int SIZE3>
void Array (T (&a)[SIZE1][SIZE2][SIZE3])
{}
```

This is just an example to demonstrate the syntax which will elegantly receive the array without any copying and also avoids confusing pointers. Also, if you are aware that you are going to use only for `int` then simply remove the typename and explicitly mention `int`. i.e.

```
template<int SIZE>
void Array (int (&a)[SIZE]); // explicitly mention int
```